# Query DNS server for specific IP address in all Forward Lookup Zones?

Tags: powershell, dns

I'm running Windows Server DNS for more than 100 Forward Lookup Zones.
I need to find, which Forward Lookup ZOnes or DNS entry is using a specific IP address?

So input will be: `192.0.2.4` (any IP address)
Result: any Forward lookup zones and it's DNS entries which contain the above IP addresses.

The goal here is to find the DNS entry that is no longer valid due to the old IP address.

An example that is not working:

```
Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName * | Where-Object {$_.IPv4Address.IPAddressToString -contains '192.0.2.4' }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could query your zones first and loop through them:

```
$zones = Get-DnsServerZone | where {!$_.IsReverseLookupZone -and $_.ZoneType -eq 'Primary'}
foreach ($zone in $zones) {
    Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName $zone.ZoneName |
        Where {$_.RecordData.Ipv4Address.IPAddressToString -contains '192.0.2.4'} |
            Select HostName,RecordType,Type,RecordData,Timestamp,TimeToLive,@{n='Zone';e={$zone.ZoneName}}
}
```

If you want a grid view, you use `Out-Gridview`:

```
$zones = Get-DnsServerZone | where {!$_.IsReverseLookupZone -and $_.ZoneType -eq 'Primary'}
$output = foreach ($zone in $zones) {
    Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName $zone.ZoneName |
        Where {$_.RecordData.Ipv4Address.IPAddressToString -contains '192.0.2.4'} |
            Select HostName,RecordType,Type,RecordData,Timestamp,TimeToLive,@{n='Zone';e={$zone.ZoneName}}
}
$output | Out-GridView
```

Comment: Man, thank you, you are awesome :-)
How can I set the output to Out-GridView?

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer I added a version using `out-gridview`

Comment: that's great, thank you @admin

Answer (score 1):

A basic nslookup will do that

```
nslookup 192.0.2.4
```

If there's a hit, the result will show the FQDN of the matching record (which is what you're looking for: record+zone).